# 8 bit computer graphics

Tags: theory, graphics

I'm working on learning how 8 bit computers work and operate. I know you can make a (tedious) microprocessor with a larg amount of logic gates and such, but how does it read graphics? I know [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00068U240) uses a microprocessor (PIC), but what instructions tell it to draw a pixel at x, y location. I'll go looking into how a monitor works in the mean time.

Comment: What does "read graphics" mean?

Comment: To place a pixel

Comment: I think there is an underlying misunderstanding with the terms 'computer' and 'microprocessor' here.

Comment: Maybe a better start point would be a blinking LED...

Comment: @EugeneSh. I hate how many haters there are on stackoverflow trying to remove all topics. Is the case that they insult because they have no good answers? Or is this how things just roll SO?

Comment: @Joe Believe me, it is a good advice. The question and the comment to the answer just indicating that you have  HUGE knowledge gap in the topic that just can't be filled by answers on SE. So, please, don't get offended, and start learning from simpler things.

Comment: @joe, if you really want to know from the logic gate to the pixel level, then you really need to do more background research. Others here can only give so much information per answer... I'd liken this question as being overly broad.

Comment: @Joe The chip is unlikely to be a PIC.  It is certainly some custom chip made for the game.  I was able to find a closeup of a board sold in the UK, and the chip says VK121PAL Velleman on it (so it generates TV video in PAL format),  The corresponding chip for the US would be VKxxNTSC.  Since this chip generates composite video, that is all done by [timing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTSC) and is nothing like the X,Y pixel addressing used by LCDs.

Comment: I don't see why it couldn't be a PIC.  The graphics for a game of pong are quite simple to generate and it should be possible to do so with a simple microcontroller.  Composite video signals are not all that complicated.

Comment: @tcrosley the [manual for the module](https://www.velleman.eu/downloads/0/minikits/manuals/manual_mk121.pdf) states that it's a pre-programmed PIC16C505.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you will have a video RAM somewhere where the memory locations correspond to the pixels on the display.  This is generally special-purpose memory as it has to be read out continuously and written to the display.  In the case of a standard computer monitor, the video card will read pixel data out of memory and send it to the display via VGA, HDMI, or DVI.  In the case of a dot matrix display connected to a microcontroller, the video memory generally resides within the display control chip on the display.  The control chip continuously reads out the memory and drives the pixels on the display.  The CPU then just has to write to the video RAM where it wants the pixels turned on or off.  In computer monitors, several bytes correspond to each pixel.  In monochrome display, each bit in each byte could correspond to a pixel.  If you want to turn on some pixel x,y all you need to know is what memory location corresponds to that pixel and update it accordingly, either setting the color you want or turning on the specific bit that corresponds to that pixel.  To the microprocessor, everything is just a number; there is nothing inherent about the video ram that says 'this is video data' aside from the fact that it gets written to the display.

Edit: as for your 'pong' game, this is a completely different animal.  The chip on there generates a composite video signal on the fly.  If you just want to draw some dots or lines, this isn't terribly complicated.  The basic idea is that a frame of video is represented by a series of lines, transmitted in sequence.  The lines are marked by horizontal sync pulses, and the frames are marked by vertical sync pulses.  In old CRT monitors, the sync signals are used to control the scanning of the electron beam across the display while everything in between the sync signals is sent directly to the electron gun to change the intensity.  All the microcontroller needs to do is generate the sync pulses at the right times and then set the output 'high' when the electron gun is currently pointed at the spot on the display that the controller wants to make light up white.  This can either be done with a video RAM, reading out one pixel at a time, or with a bunch of carefully-configured timers and counters.  This chip doesn't have enough RAM to store a whole frame, so most likely they are using the timer method.  The game has two paddles and a ball.  To generate the video signal, the controller generates one line of video at a time like so: generate an HSYNC pulse, wait until the first paddle column comes around, draw one point on the paddle if it currently intersects that line, wait until the ball column comes around, draw the ball if the ball is supposed to be on that line, wait for the second paddle column to come around, draw the paddle if it intersects the current line, wait the right amount of time for the next HSYNC pulse, and repeat.  There are some details with respect to generating the VSYNC signal as well as only drawing on the visible area of the display as well.

Comment: Ah, so the pixel location is told in binary digits?

Comment: Well, not exactly.  You could have a subroutine that takes the pixel location as a binary number and then goes and adjusts the corresponding memory location, though.  The memory ADDRESS corresponds to which pixel you are interested in and the memory CONTENT then determines what color it is.

Comment: "This is generally special-purpose memory as it has to be read out continuously and written to the display" -- while this is true for more modern systems, the question asked about 8-bit systems.  Most 8-bit processors didn't use the bus all of the time, and there was enough time left over to manage reading the data for a low resolution, low colour-depth screen.  E.g. a 6502 only uses its bus during half of each cycle, so the other half can be used by display hardware to fetch data to display.  Possibly the easiest to understand example is the Apple II, which is well documented online.

Answer (score 1):

While a 32 or 64-bit microprocessor contained in the PC on your desk will have video RAM that is mapped within the address space of the CPU, that is usually not the case for most 8-bit microcontrollers, which is the subject of the question.

8-bit processors generally don't have more than 65K of memory (addressed using a 16-bit address field).

Older 8-bit microprocessors, such as the 6502 and 6800, had external address and data busses since they didn't contain any memory within the microprocessor.  So early computers like the Apple // did have memory-mapped video -- but it took away memory available to be used as general RAM for the programs.  As display sizes grew, the 16K buffer (1/4 of the 64K available space) allocated to graphics wasn't big enough and elaborate banking schemes were devised to access all of the video memory.  Each manufacturer had their own scheme.  It was a nightmare.

In general, 8-bit microcontrollers don't have external address and data busses, since they want to allow for as many pins for peripheral (GPIO, SPI, I2C, UART) as possible.  So it is not feasible to do memory mapping of displays using these chips.

So most displays (OLED, TFT, LCD etc.) used with microcontrollers are connected to a display controller, which in turn is connected to the microcontroller via a serial interface such as SPI or I2C.  In addition to the serial interface, these controllers have a data mode and control mode controlled by a D/C line. To write a pixel or group of pixels, the microcontroller first sets the D/C line to command mode, and then sends a command to the controller to set up an X,Y cursor position.  Then the microcontroller sends a command to prepare the display controller for the writing of pixels.

To write out the data for the actual pixels, the microcontroller sets the D/C line to data mode and then sends the data for one or more pixels -- one byte for 8-bit color, two bytes for 15 or 16-bit color, and three bytes for 24-bit color.  After each pixel the display controller automatically increments the display address, so any addtional pixels will be placed in the correct posotion.

There are some microcontrollers that have built-in LCD display controllers (such as the PIC24FJ64GA310) but they are by far the exception and typically used for smaller displays (16 characters by two lines etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the chip on that board is just a PIC? The chip I see in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fCbjLoJu1ZU) has custom markings on it. It may be a custom device with audio and video hardware built in. Normal 8-bit microcontrollers don't support audio or video directly. You need external hardware to make that happen. If you want to play with visual output devices, you might start with something simple like a character. TV video is not trivial.

For audio, you could generate square waves with a PWM module. The microcontroller could probably drive a tiny speaker directly.

Comment: It is VERY possible to generate real-time standard-definition video in an 8-bit microcontroller, but it requires a thorough knowledge of the hardware on the chip as well as some very careful assembly-language programming. And there's a long tradition of using PIC chips to do it, dating from as far back as 1992, with this [Single-chip Video Wind Gauge](http://dtweed.com/circuitcellar/caj00032.htm#456)

Comment: Wow, that's pretty impressive! I was thinking you'd at least need a DAC or some sort of NES-style support chip. I forgot about black and white graphics.